# How would you do this in canvas drawing

Tags: android

How would you draw something like this programmatically in a ondraw method?  I know how to draw lines or squares, but to have an image inside a squarebox that has an arrow, is kind of confusing for me
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just break the drawing up in different elements:

- a gray box
- a white rounded rectangle
- a white rectangle
- a blue rectangle
- a blue rounded rectangle
- a blue triangle
- a red heart (I would just try to find a font with a nice heart)
- the text in white.

Draw it all to the canvas in this order and you are fine.

Comment: Thank you can you advise on how to do 1) rounded rectangle 2) the heart (or any image).

Comment: `RectF rect = new RectF(10, 10, 50, 50); c.drawRoundRect(rect, 3, 3, p);` gives you a rounded rect. For the heart, I would just use a text based heart and print it to the screen. Use a font like Windings (I am sure there must be a heart in there).

Comment: Thank you. I have a heart which is an image as it is provided by designer so I need to use that. I guess, drawbitmap, right?

Comment: Actually that wouldnt work as the squares will cover the rounded corners!

Comment: You should make the rectangle smaller so that they only overlap at one side.

Comment: Great. Good luck!